# Angularjs Resource Multiple Parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I want to use resource method with multiple parameters.I tried like this,

```
var mytest = $resource('/localhost/:id&:test', {id: '@id',test:'@test'});

mytest.getCached({id:'1',test:'test'}, function() { .. })
```

but it does not work.Is ***'/localhost/:id&:test'*** definition is correct? or Is there a any wrong part?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i had that error earlier and i solve that with "#" you can try;

```
var mytest = $resource('/localhost/#:id&:test', {id: '@id',test:'@test'});
```